# Agregar label en gráfica Highcharts JavaScript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estoy intentando agregar un label o leyenda en la gráfica para poder mostrarla en el centro de la gráfica hasta arriba.

Este label debe llevar el valor de la variable Leyenda.

Si pueden ayudarme muchas gracias.

```js
var Cuota=2000;
var CuotaGrupo=1500; 
var San=200; 
var Tavil=700;
var Otros=100; 
var Frente='Frente';
var Leyenda = 4000;      
      var contador = 0;
     var contador2 = 0;
     var arreglo = [];
     Highcharts.chart('subcontainer', {
      chart: {
       type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
       text: 'Ingreso  ' + Frente
      },
      subtitle: {
       text: 'Subtitulo'
      },
      xAxis: {
       categories: [Frente,  ],
       crosshair: true
      },
      yAxis: {
       min: 0,
       title: {
        text: 'TN '
       }
      },
      tooltip: {
       headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
       pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' + '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} tons</b></td></tr>',
       footerFormat: '</table>',
       shared: true,
       useHTML: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
       column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
         enabled: true,
        }
       }
      },
      legend: {
 
       layout: 'vertical',
       align: 'right',
       verticalAlign: 'top',
       x: -40,
       y: 80,
       floating: true,
       borderWidth: 1,
       backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
       shadow: true
      },
      credits: {
       enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
       name: 'Cuota',
       data: [Cuota]
      }, {
       name: 'CuotaGrupo',
       data: [CuotaGrupo]
      }, {
       name: 'San',
       data: [San]
      }
            , {
       name: 'Tavil',
       data: [Tavil]
      }
            , {
       name: 'Otros',
       data: [Otros]
      }]
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="subcontainer" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: no entiendo, intentastes crear una variable y agregarla a la leyenda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta opcion . le sume los valores que tu quieres

```
var subtotal =  San + Tavil + Otros;
```

y luego los muestro

```js
var Cuota=2000;
var CuotaGrupo=1500; 
var San=200; 
var Tavil=700;
var Otros=100; 
var Frente='Frente';
var subtotal =  San + Tavil + Otros;    
      var contador = 0;
     var contador2 = 0;
     var arreglo = [];
     Highcharts.chart('subcontainer', {
      chart: {
       type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
       text: 'Ingreso  ' + Frente
      },
      subtitle: {
       text: 'Subtitulo'
      },
      xAxis: {
       categories: [Frente,  ],
       crosshair: true
      },
      yAxis: {
       min: 0,
       title: {
        text: 'TN '
       }
      },
      tooltip: {
       headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
       pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' + '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} tons</b></td></tr>',
       footerFormat: '<tr><td><span >(Total: ' + subtotal + ')</span></td></tr></table>',
       shared: true,
       useHTML: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
       column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
         enabled: true,
        }
       }
      },
      legend: {

       layout: 'vertical',
       align: 'right',
       verticalAlign: 'top',
       x: -40,
       y: 80,
       floating: true,
       borderWidth: 1,
       backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
       shadow: true
      },
      credits: {
       enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
       name: 'Cuota',
       data: [Cuota]
      }, {
       name: 'CuotaGrupo',
       data: [CuotaGrupo]
      }, {
       name: 'San',
       data: [San]
      }
            , {
       name: 'Tavil',
       data: [Tavil]
      }
            , {
       name: 'Otros',
       data: [Otros]
      }]
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="subcontainer" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @JackNavaRow, saludos cordiales.

Comment: Si muy útil, ya que no me había percatado que donde agregaste el valor yo podía agregar html. Gracias.